# Magento 2 - Category attributes save to wrong store ID

Tags: php, magento2

I am running the latest Magento 2 CE (2.3.3) in **Single Store Mode**

When I edit a category's attribute in the Magento 2 admin, it saves to the wrong store ID.

The database shows that the attribute, in this case content, to store ID 0 and not to store ID 1.

```sql
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_text WHERE entity_id = 27 AND attribute_id = 47;
```

It shows the following data:

```
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| value_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value        |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|      444 |           47 |        0 |        27 | <p>Test3</p> |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

While it should show:

```
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| value_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value        |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|      444 |           47 |        0 |        27 | <p>Test3</p> |
|      445 |           47 |        1 |        27 | <p>Test3</p> |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

I read [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/154287/58853). I confirmed I already did all steps in the accepted answer.

A [different answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252425/58853) to the same question talks about manually editing the database to include the row for store 1. I confirmed this works but it is off course not an option. We can't ask our client to edit the database manually.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me, please post steps to reproduce at 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues
as I don't see any issue that's currently opened on it, but I remember some other issues related to scopes in admin, so this one can still be not working correctly.